# Java inheritance class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have main class:

```
public class MainClass{
    private int firstVal;
    private int secVal;

    public MainClass(int firstVal,int secVal){
      this.firstVal=firstVal;
      this.secVal=secVal;
    }
}
```

and second class that extend this class

```
 public class SecClass extends MainClass{
     public SecClass(int firstVal,int secVal){
         super(firstVal,secVal)
     }
 }
```

I want to know How can I use the values firstVal and secVal in the SecClass? 
    super.firstVal   ??
or that I have to defind the values in agian?

Thanks

Comment: They are `private`, so you can't.

Comment: You can change it to protected to access in the subclass. You can see the complete details in this link 

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html. 

Access Levels
Modifier Class Package Subclass World
public         Y Y Y          Y   
protected Y Y Y          N
no modifier Y Y N          N
private         Y N N          N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just mark them as `protected` instead of `private`:

```
public class MainClass {
    protected int firstVal;
    protected int secVal;
    //rest of your class...
}
```

If you want to keep them as `private`, you can make getters and setters for this fields and mark these methods as `public` or `protected`, depending the visibility you want/need for them:

```
public class MainClass {
    private int firstVal;
    //its value can be retrieved by any class
    public int getFirstVal() {
        return this.firstVal;
    }
    //its value can only be modified by subclasses of MainClass
    protected void setFirstVal(int firstVal) {
        this.firstVal = firstVal;
    }
    //similar for the other field...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a table about the scope of `public`, `private` and `protected`, from where you'll understand why `private variable` cannot be used in the `child class`, (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private))

```
Modifier    | Class | Package | Subclass | World
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
public      |  ✔    |    ✔    |    ✔     |   ✔
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
protected   |  ✔    |    ✔    |    ✔     |   ✘
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
no modifier |  ✔    |    ✔    |    ✘     |   ✘
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
private     |  ✔    |    ✘    |    ✘     |   ✘
```

Answer (score 0):

You need getters and setters in your `MainClass`. Then you can call `super.getFirstVal()`

Add these to your `MainClass`

```
public int getFirstVal() {
  return firstVal;
}

public int getSecVal() {
  return secVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with getters and setters. But if you believe the subclass should be able to access them, then declare `firstVal` and `secVal` protected. Then you can access them directly in the subclass:

```
subclassInstance.firstVal
subclassInstance.secVal
```

Private variables are not allowed to be accessed by anyone or any subclass for that matter.  Protected variables are similar except subclasses may access them. You can still call the `super()` constructor; it is good practice to let parent constructors initialize their own varibles.

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the same package, just remove `private` access modifier. If not, you need to add `protected` or `public` (very bad idea). In general you should not expose your fields to the sub-classes like this as you cannot know what they will do with them.